# Is there a Photoshop filter for extracting and merging details from bracketed photos?

Tags: photoshop, hdr, bracketing

Here is an example of a bracketed photo with a range of detail on both ends of the exposure spectrum:

[http://www.peciva.com/images/blog/hdr-necropolis/bracketed-exposures.jpg](http://www.peciva.com/archives/2009/06/hdr_necropolis.shtml)

My question is: is there a filter (likely in Photoshop) that can take a set of bracketed photos and extracted/merge the photos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are essentially talking about HDR. You can do it in Photoshop (File > Automate > Merge to HDR), or you can use dedicated software like Photomatix. It is tricky to get good looking results.

When done well they can be stunning - unfortunately they aren't often done well.

Comment: +1 @ElendilTheTall: Thanks, HDR being "High Dynamic Range", correct? Also, for those reading this, these appear to be finished examples of this post-production method: http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=high+dynamic+range+photography

Comment: High Dynamic Range, yes: in other words from the very darkest to the very brightest.

Comment: There's different ways to compress a high-dynamic range scene into a final image, typically called an "HDR image", although really the dynamic range is just compressed — the output media isn't (usually) special. One technique is called "tone mapping", while the simple approach of blending bracketed exposures is "exposure blending".